# ReactJS - setObjectState not updating state inside AJAX call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update the state of the record object which I created below:

```
const[record, setRecord] = useState([]);
```

I am calling a function named `createOrder` inside `forEach`. On getting a successful response from an ajax call, I update the state of the record object. Below is my ajax code snippet where I am updating the state of the record

```
const createOrder = () => {
    axios.post(`${getServiceURL()}/order`, orderRecord, headerConfig)
        .then(response => {
            setRecord((prevData) => [response.data, ...prevData]);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

`setRecord` updates the record object only with the last response I got from ajax.

Comment: Don't call `setRecord` inside a loop (you could do `...prevData` instead of `...record`, but you're doing more computations than needed by doing that and your data won't come back in a predictable order), instead get all your promise data in an array, and then set your state once you have that array. You can use `Promise.all()` to help with that. At the moment, your function seems like it always does the same API call for each element you iterate over, or are you getting a different response back each iteration?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I am adding prevData instead of record inside setXXX. Edited the code for the same. Also, I am making ajax calls to different APIs each time. For simplicity purposes, I removed that code. Please tell me in detail how to use Promise.all(). Thanks

Comment: See [Adib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800270/5648954) for a Promise.all() approach